# MotionEyeOs: How to connect to rpi from a different router

Tags: networking

My Router Setup:

R1 (Modem router) 
->My main router to the internet
->SSID = "Router1" 
->IP: 192.168.1.1
->Dhcp server
->this is where my rpi (motioneyeos) is connected

R2 
-Connected to R1 via R1's LAN port and R2's LAN port
-SSID = "Router2" 
-IP: 192.168.1.2
-dhcp server disabled

R3
-Connected to R2's LAN port and R3's LAN port
-SSID = "Router3" 
-IP: 192.168.1.3
-dhcp server disabled

Problem:
When my computer or phone is connected to R2 or R3, I cant access the RPi. But when im connected to R1, i can access the RPi. Is my router setup the problem? What do i need to do to fix this issue?

Note:
I can access each router's web interface (the login page for each routers) from any router (R1, R2  R3)

PS:
Im not good with computer networks. XD

Comment: How are you connecting to the Pi  do you know it's IP address?

Comment: This seems like a routing problem, and you don't mention anything about your routes.

Comment: @Bra1n Yes. I know Pi's IP address and that's how I'm connecting to it.

Comment: Try doing a tracert to the IP address of the Pi from your computer when connected to to R3 and report back.

Comment: Im having Request timed out all the time. Should i change my router config? what are the possible solutions for this?

Comment: what is the ip address of your Pi ? Please copy the output from the tracert and paste it on here

Comment: Here:  https://pastebin.com/R83r01SM

But if I connected in R1 with that IP (192.168.1.14), I can connect to my pi and can see the video footage of the  camera